# How to convert NSIndexpath into NSInteger or simply int?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to convert a nsindexpath var into NsInteger or simply an int.
e.g:

```
 int rowIndex = [mGoogleBaseTable selectedRow];
 //mGoogleBaseTable is a NSTable type in Macdevelopement..
```

&&

```
int rowIndex = [mGoogleBaseTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
//mGoogleBaseTable is a UITableView type in Iphone (iOS)Development.
```

selectedRow returns NSInteger simply but indexPathForSelectedRow returns a NSIndexPath..

Please help me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If

```
NSIndexPath *p = ... // some indexpath
```

then

```
NSInteger row = p.row;
NSInteger section = p.section;
```

That's all!

Comment: thank you.. complete work is p.row but i no understand p.section.

Comment: @AnilMetatagg the section is only relevant if you have more than one section.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe, this is can help you

```
NSInteger variable = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: also can used like yourTextField.tag = indexPath.row to track and create conditions inside your your custom cells, say if you want to update data inside a mutable array..

Answer (score 8):

In **Swift**:

```
    let section: Int = indexPath.section
    let row: Int = indexPath.row
```

Answer (score 7):

I prefer doing it this way

```
NSNumber *selRow = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: In that case better use `NSNumber *selrow = @(indexPath.row);` for readability

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert into int by,

NSIndexPath *path =  ... // some indexpath

int row = (int)path.row;

Answer (score -1):

In swift :

1. Associate your collection view to your var :

   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
2. In `prepareForSegue` func, you can call :

   var indexPath =  collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()