# How to convert NSIndexPath to NSInteger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsindexpath, nsinteger

I have searched and found a previous answer for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574449/how-to-convert-nsindexpath-into-nsinteger-or-simply-int).  The problem is that the answer marked as a solution does not work. Inside my tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, I have

```
NSInteger *currentRow = indexPath.row;
```

and it gives me the warning 'Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSInteger *'(aka 'int *') with an expression of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int').

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

NSInteger is not a class, so it doesn't need an asterisk:

```
NSInteger currentRow = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: also very useful is to track the index.row by assigning it to a yourView.tag or yourLabel.tag so you can access information from custom cells and the like...so it would be yourTextView.tag = indexPath.row